# What's going to happen if someone has access to my Bip32 root key?

Tags: blockchain, private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, xpub

Can my bitcoin get stolen if someone else has access to my Bip32 root key?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are talking about the root *private* key (xprv) then yes, he will be able to steal all your current **and future** coins as long as you keep generating addresses from that key. It’s basically the same as him having access to your mnemonic phrase.